# Why am i geting the value from keyboard with while( in.hasNext() )

Tags: java, while-loop

I am a java beginer, my confusion regarding the following program is, why it assigns the value, i enter from keyboard at `while( in.hasNext() )`to the `total` variable, and process the value of `total = in.intNext()` for the while condition ?

**Confusion**

```
  System.out.print("Enter an Integer value or ctrl+z to terminate: ");
  while ( in.hasNext()  ) // Check for New Vlaue 
   {    
    System.out.print("Enter an Integer value or ctrl+z to terminate: ");
    total += in.nextInt();  // Take input for Count
    count++;
   }
```

My confusion is the condition checking of `while loop`, which normally checks a condition first, and then proceed to the statements, but in this program, when i enter an Integer Value at the `while( in.hasNext() )`, it not only makes the condition true, but also assign that value to the `total` variable, so my question,

Why does it assigns the value, instead of taking another value from me at `total = in.nextInt()` ?

Since i looked for `hasNext()` method, which only returns *True* if there is a value.

**Complete Program**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Practice
{
 public static void main( String[] args )
 {
  int count=0; 
  int total = 0;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter an Integer value or ctrl+z to terminate: ");
  while ( in.hasNext()  ) // Check for New Vlaue 
   {    
    System.out.print("Enter an Integer value or ctrl+z to terminate: ");
    total += in.nextInt();  // Take input for Count
    count++;
   }
  System.out.printf("\nTatal values are: %d\nToatl of count is : %d",count,total);
 } // end main
} // end class Practice
```

Comment: "why it assigns the value to the count variable?" - because it sums up all integers the user enters... you've written the program so only you know why it does what it does :-)

Comment: I would take a look at `java.io.Console` since Java 6.

Comment: Don't you mean to have `count++; total += in.nextInt();`? I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question entirely, but I will mention that `count += in.next()` is synonymous to `count = count + in.next()`

Comment: i think you want to do `total += in.NextInt(); count ++;` ?

Comment: My Confusion is the `while loop` which first chek the condition and then proceed to the statments of the loop, but over here instead of checking thee condtion `in.hasNext()` first, it runs the statements  and then check the condition.
 
@PeterLawrey the reason i add 'Total' variable, is my Confussion, so it can tell the number of time statements of the 'while loop' are accesed

Comment: @Thousand yes, `total += in.NextInt(); count ++;` this is the right way to write the program, but my confusion is `while loop`, which normally checks a condition first, and then proceed to the statements,  but in this program, when i enter an `Integer Value` at the `while( in.hasNext() )`, it makes the condition true, as well as, put that value to the `count` variable, so my question, Why does it assigns the value, instead of taking another value from me at ` count = in.nextInt()` ?

Comment: `hasXxx` on checks the value is there without consuming it. `nextXxx` gets the next value assuming you have decided you want to.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: your answer was highly helpful, but i have other question, related to the same topic, Why do i get an error, if i declare a new integer, after the body of `while loop', and assigns it with `in.nextInt()` that is `int newVal = in.nextInt();`

Error Specifics:
> Exception in thread"main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>
> at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
Note: My program do get compile, and show result accurately, till `int

Comment: Note: My program do get compile, and runs properly, till new declaration but not after that, i.e it shows error message when control structure comes to `int newVal = in.nextInt()` and programs comes to halt.

Comment: That is because the next thing is not a number. You can check this with `hasNextInt` You may need to call `nextLine()` between lines.

Answer (score 1):

the value from the keyboard is not read on the `while( in.hasNext() )` line, but in the  `count += in.nextInt();` statement

Comment: this is what is making me confuse, since while loop first chek the condition and then proceed to the statments of the loop, but over here it does not check the condtion first , but instead, it run the statements first, with out checking the condition in.hasNext()

Comment: no it checks the condition, but does not take the data from the in at that point (on the while( in.hasNext() ) line)

Comment: i have checked it again, it do take the value at `While (in.hasNext())` but as Peter has mentioned, it only cheks the value, and assigns it when the statement 'total+= in.nextInt()' is called.

To make it sure, i made a couple of changes to the code:

    int val = 0; // Variable for storing IntegerValue.

Comment: To make it sure, i made a couple of changes to the code:

    `int val = 0; // Variable for storing IntegerValue.
    System.out.print("Enter an Integer value or ctrl+z to terminate: ");
    while ( in.hasNext()  ) // Check for New Vlaue 
     { 
      System.out.print("IntegerValue before input is : " + val);
      val = in.nextInt(); 
      System.out.println("\nIntegerValue after input is : " + val);
      System.out.print("\nEnter an Integer value or ctrl+z to terminate: ");
      total += val;
      count++;
    }`

Comment: The result is , after giving an Integer value at `while` , it will print out, old value of variable`val` before `in.nextInt()`statement and instead of taking value from user, it will just assigns the user value, provided at `while continuation condition` and proceed to the next statement, that is , prints out the new value of variable `val`. Once this loop gets completed, the new value is taken again at the `while continuation condition`.